# How can I recover data from my external hard disk after formatting using the Media Creation Tool?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, media-creation-tool

I had a lot of important data in WDmypassport external HD but I made this HD bootable (using media creation tool) without knowing that it can wipe off my data backup. I am new to this and I admit this was a big blunder. Can I get the complete data back, organized like before. Is there any way? There are a lot of recovery tools but they all give data unorganized, which can be a big loss in my case.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device BTW, your title doesn't match your apparent issue - it sounds like you already reformatted & overwrote the data.

Comment: Typical data recovery software would be used.  However, do not expect to be sucessful, since you overwrote the data.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you already formatted the disk and created a Windows installation disk out of it.  Some of the data has been overwritten, and the file system has been replaced by the one created for the Windows installation.  If you really need that data, don't write anything else to it and bring it to a data recovery business.  You might be able to restore it yourself with a lot of research, but if you want it soon, a data recovery business may be able to get some of it back.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to do an "undo" to get the data back to the organized stated.

The best is to try to recover via some of the recovery tools (even in that case don't expect 100% success rate, especially if you have written to the newly formatted drive) and organize again manually.

I would recover all of the data, save them elsewhere and started with the "organization of files after"

Comment: Can you also recommend a good software?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic for Super User.